# Not able to use created table as composite type - postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a composite type in postgreSQl

In the documentation its given if we create a table a type for it already created.

I run the following code first

```
create table industry(
id Serial,
name text )
```

After this code I try to run

```
create table company(
id serial,
name text,
industries industry[])
```

I am getting the following error on running the code

`ERROR:  type "industry" does not exist`

Comment: I cannot reproduce. This works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e7aa5df8e5712da29478eb9b5f569c1

Comment: Either you forgot to run the first create statement or you ran it in a different database. This code should work. Could you share the whole script?

Comment: Its weird, when I ran entire create table in one go it worked. Earlier I had created table industry using the PgAdmin GUI and was trying to create table company post that through writing the create table command.

Comment: So most llikely you were using a different database in one of the connections, e.g. postgres (maintenance db) .. it happens a lot :) hope you solved your problem.